# huge right margin html/css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build my first website. I am wondering why I got a huge right margin when I set that value 0 everywhere.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    .........
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
         <div id="branding">
          <h1>AUTO SERVICE</h1>
          <h2>zoo</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

the CSS code:

```
body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
}
```

/*Global*/

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

/*Header*/

```
header{
  background: #03244D;
  color: #9AA7B7;
  padding-top: 10px;
  min-height: 70px;
  line-height: 0.5;
}
```

/*Branding*/

```
header #branding{
    font: 25px/0.8 "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: 160%;
    text-align: center;
    float: center;
}
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: There is no such thing as the option "center" for "float". > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container is set to only be 80% width.  The remaining 20%, minus 20 pixels for the left-margin, will likely be your margin on the right-hand side.  Try changing the width of your container in your CSS, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I should have kept width 80% if I wanted to build a response website.